# Heroku not displaying express images

Tags: express, heroku, handlebars.js

I have deployed an app to Heroku but my images arent appearing. They all work fine in localhost. The app runs using express and handlebars.
I have seen it could be as a result of case sensitivity and have checked the case is the same for .png. So i assume its a pathing issue. I have used background.png in CSS at that works correctly its only images referenced in HTML.

Heres the image

```
<a href="/"><img class="logo" alt="logo" src="images/logo.png"></a> <!-- Logo image -->
```

Localhost

[image]

Heroku

[image]

app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

The project structure
[image]

background.png CSS

```
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url("../Images/background.png");
```

Comment: What does the Javascript console and the Network tab of your browser devtools tell you about the URL being used to retrieve your image?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Of course, but what is the precise URL of the image that wasn't found? It's possible your HTML code is looking in the wrong directory. That's how you troubleshoot these torn-image-icon problems.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the syntax images was lower case when the folder name is Images. Creating the 404.